# Workday integration with php and linux endpoint file delivery

Tags: php, linux, workday-api

EDITED TO CLARIFY

**What I did on workday:**

I have created a Web services EIB using a report. I have access to all the fields in the primary business object.

**How did I test this:**

Ran the EIB and delivered the output as "Workday attachment"  - EIB ran sucessfully.

**What I did next:**

To output the EIB to a remote location - I changed the EIB delivery to HTTP/SSL option.

**What was done on the Linux box (endpoint):**

Created a folder and assigned it with permission 777 owned by the apache user

**Running the EIB:**

I then ran the EIB with the above setting and the EIB completed successfully. I have attached an image with the result

[image]

**What is the problem?**

No file is created in the endpoint.

**So what did I do next?**

Since I was not getting any document at the endpoint I thought of getting the input and dumping it to a file using PHP. So I used the script below and created a page called capture.php to capture the input.

```
<?PHP
$tempfilename = "workday.wd";
$tempdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
try{
        $myfile = fopen("../../../tempdata/".$tempfilename, "w");
        fwrite($myfile, $tempdata);
        fclose($myfile);
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }


?>
```

**What happened when I did this?**

I updated the EIB and ran it again and this time the EIB failed.

**My questions are as follows:**

1. What is the trigger for workday to return a "sucessfull" operation?
   Why is it saying it was successful when it was not.
2. The next question is - what is the best way to find out what is
   being output from Workday
3. The last questions is - how can I capture the output (irrespective
   of format, object type etc) in PHP and dump it to a file.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: To summarise @JayBlanchard We are not clairvoyant. If you want us to help you, you have to help us to do that by giving us ALL the information that would allow us to do so. Currently you have a lot of noise words, but very little information. As with most SO questions if you post us some code to help us understand what you are doing you will get a much better and swifter response from the community

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Edited for clarity

Comment: So now your question has been re-opened

Answer (score 0):

OK - I have an official answer to this problem.

This is what I have been told by the workday integration specialists - there is a known issue with HTTP transport options if you use an outbound EIB. The best way to get around this is to use WD Studio to build the integration.

I hope this helps somebody.